# Why do apps grow when moved to SD card?

Tags: installation, sd-card

I have a rather small app that shows as 684 KB on internal memory. When I move it to the SD card, it has 500 KB left on the internal memory and 2 MB on USB memory.

Why do the moved 184 KB grow to be 2 MB on the SD card ?